# Compiling Documents Based on Keywords in a Longer Text

Tags: compiling, sorting, database

I'm a teacher and I use LaTeX for all my exams.  I would like to create a database of exam questions and attach multiple keywords to each question.  Then, I would like to be able to generate a document that lists all of the questions pertaining to any particular keyword - or set of keywords.

Can I do this using BibTex?  Other thoughts?

Comment: The package exsheets, I believe, does what you're looking for.